# Is WCF netMsmqBinding multithreaded?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

We are using .net WCF with netMsmqBinding.
Is the netMsmqBinding multi threaded?
Is there a way to change the bindings to use single thread?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? All WCF bindings are inherently multi-threaded. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I think he is trying to prevent messages from being processed out of order. If the queue reader is multi-threaded, it may finish processing message 2 before is finishes with message 1.

Comment: Thant's exactly what I am trying to do. Due to multi threading, the messages are processed out of order creating issues in our application. Is there a way to change this default behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

To process the messages in order add a servicebehavior attribute to your service and set the instancecontentmode to single and the concurrenycmode to single

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single , ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single )]
public class Service : IService...
```